# p tag overlapping the grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i’m creating my freecodecamp personal portfolio project and finded a problem that I cannot fix. I'm using the grid system and the `<p>` tag is overlapping the `<img>` tag. The `<p>` continues in a unique line and overflows everything. It's like the grid system isn’t working correctly, I don’t know. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <h2 class="text-left">Lucas Navarro</h2>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <img src="https://scontent.ffor2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/1239616_823750807639024_3113666417692842617_n.jpg?oh=c3639eb24282a6493c652c9e44e065dc&oe=5A108s445" class="img-responsive myPic" alt="pic">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like someone wants help with homework!

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Example fiddle:

```css
p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <h2 class="text-left">Lucas Navarro</h2>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <img src="https://scontent.ffor2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/1239616_823750807639024_3113666417692842617_n.jpg?oh=c3639eb24282a6493c652c9e44e065dc&oe=5A108s445" class="img-responsive myPic" alt="pic">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet as style in your head section of page. This will wrap your text inside its parent div.

```
.textwrapper {  
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* for Webkit */    
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* for Firefox */     
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* for Opera versions less than v7 */    
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* for Opera v7 */     
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* for IE */ 
}
```

Then, assign the `textwrapper` class to your `p` tag:

```
<p class="textwrapper">blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
```